# Double bind jar dependency

Tags: java, jar

I have one Java project (Project A) in which I load other jars. These jars (Project B) all have one class implements an application interface. In order to know that interface, project b has to have project A as library.

Now, when starting project A, it loads the jar of project B, looks for the application class, gets the constructor and trys to create an object, but this fails:
The constructor from B's class creates an object implementing the interface which is known to project B, ALTHOUGH this is the same interface as in project A, but it seems that these two are not seen as being equal.

How can I solve this double bind dependency?

Edit:
This is how I try to create an application in project A:

```
clazz = Class.forName(className, true, loader);
ctor = (Constructor<? extends Application>) clazz.getConstructor();
Application app = ctor.newInstance();
```

The exception occurs in the third line where it says app is of type SpecificApplication (which is defined in the loaded jar and implements the Application interface) and thus cannot be cast to Application.

Comment: AFAIK, Java deals with these kind of circular dependencies automagically. How are you running your program and loading the JAR files?

Comment: You can have two classes which depend on each other in different JAR without a problem.

Comment: See edit: I run the project A which loads the jar file and loads the class with the given name.

Comment: What is "project"? Eclipse project? Is this OSGi? Any other classloader magic going on? Try to create a very small example and post it here.

Comment: Classes are unique per classloader. So if you get an error that looks like "class X is not equal to class X" then you might have class X loaded by two different classloaders.

Answer (score 0):

Put the interface in another jar, which is referenced by projects A and B.

Comment: This should not be necessary